# CSS: targeting siblings but with unknown position

Tags: css

Ok, I'm stuck trying to solve this one with CSS only although I'm not entirely sure if it's possible, so before I resort to JavaScript I need to ask here.

I need to target a sibling with the class `column-title` of the first `<li>` in the following list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="column-title">Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li class="column-title">Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Consider that the sibling can be in ***any*** position, for example:

(5th spot)

```
<ul>
    <li class="column-title">Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li class="column-title">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

(3rd spot)

```
<ul>
    <li class="column-title">Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="column-title">Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I don't think this is possible with CSS only, right?

Thanks.

***EDIT--***

Oh boy, I found the solution:

Use the **sibling combinator: ~**

```
.column-title ~ .column-title { background:#ddd; }
```

This way the property will be applied to ANY sibling of the first `.column-title` li.

PS. I found the answer at the same time *crowjonah* was posting his. I chose his answer as the *selected answer* anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the semi-supported ["general sibling combinator"](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), `~`. Something like:

```
li.column-title ~ li.column-title {color: red;}
```

Here's [a basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Scmju/) showing it being done.

And then you might need a shim like [this](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) for IE7 support, if that's up your alley.

Seeing your update, you should know that for best results, if you are excluding the first instance of li.column-title from your siblings rule, you should specify `:first-child`:

```
ul li.column-title:first-child {color: blue;}
ul li.column-title:first-child ~ li.column-title {color: red;}​
```

Comment: That's correct crowjonah, the **sibling combinator** is the answer. No need for the ie7-js though, IE7 supports the sibling combinator. Just for reference, this is a nice post from NetTuts: [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/). Thanks!

Comment: +1 amazing I've gone this long without knowing about this - good to know

Comment: @crowjonah As of right now I don't think this case necessarily needs to use the `:first-child` pseudo class because in the selector `.column-title ~ .column-title` this is already implied: the first `.column-title` is, well... the first. I'm using the first `.column-title` as a point of reference only, not for styling. The styling of the first `.column-title` is being done with simply `.column-title {...}`. Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a not filter:

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3WwP/) to demonstrate.

```
ul>li.column-title:not(:first-child) {
  color: red;
}​
```

Since it's css3, it won't be supported in pre IE9

Comment: Because the negation pseudo-class is even [less-well supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t37) than the [general-sibling combinator](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t30)?

Comment: Yes, it is: but you posted your answer as a (possibly rhetorical) question. And the compatibility issues remain. I'm not intending to discount your answer, and I'm *certainly* not intending to down-vote (it is a useful answer), but, even so: compatibility is not good for the negation-selector, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, I see your comment was more of a response to my questioning post - comes across much differently that way :)

Comment: Sorry, I often forget two important things: I have a...*weird* sense of humour, and it's hard to convey *any* word-play via the internet, in cold text. Sigh...But yeah, it was intended more as a response to the question, than a criticism (as noted: it *is* a useful answer). =)

Comment: Did not know about the `:not` filter/pseudo-class. However, the sibling combinator works just as well and it has better browser support. See why I post here in SO? Because I (we) get these kind of incredibly helpful answers we don't get anywhere else, not even conferences. Gave you an upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed - learned more on SO than any other single source - the sibling combinator was totally new to me.